disk full after leaving audacity recording unattended
I fell asleep while audacity was recording and when I woke up the disk was full To make things worse I then deleted /var/tmp I logged in as root and re-created /var/tmp and chmod it to 777 but the disk is still full and I'm not sure of the permissions mask I put on /var/tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.1G  2.1M  1.1G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       117G   89G   23G  81% /
tmpfs           5.2G  4.1k  5.2G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  8.2k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs         66k  3.5k   57k   6% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/sda1       1.2G  6.5M  1.2G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.1G  2.7M  1.1G   1% /run/user/1000


You should never remove system related directories.
/var/tmp needs sticky bit. These 3 will set it correctly (2 commands for chmod as it makes it a bit clearer)
sudo chown root:root /var/tmp
sudo chmod 777 /var/tmp
sudo chmod +t /var/tmp

The last 2 can also be done with...
sudo chmod 1777 /var/tmp

(the 1 is sticky bit).

but the disk is still full

... so /var/tmp was not the reason? Start with df -H and add the result into the question.
Just in case: do do a reboot as what is inside /var/tmp only gets removed when the files are released. Or kill audacity

I added the output of df -H to the original question I don't think I could have formatted it with line breaks as a comment

That claims your system is not full (anymore). At least not full as in "disk space". Do you have directories with a lot of small files? (like a fileserver that stores pdf's)?
